# How do you delete all lines that begin with "string" in unix sh?

Tags: file, unix, sed, sh

How do you delete all lines in a file that begin with "string" in sh? I was thinking about using the sed command.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
grep -v '^string' yourfile.txt > stripped.txt
```

Comment: how about out of the same file?

Comment: Can't really do that with grep. but you could output to a temp file then `mv tempfile origfile`. If you want true in-place editing, then sed/perl/awk would need to be used.

Comment: how would I use those then? :D

Comment: http://ptankov.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/howto-delete-a-line-in-place-with-gnu-sed/

Comment: didn't work, only reprinted the lines EXCEPT the lines containing the string

Comment: actually that was my error, it DID how ever make a new file with the filename plus -e at the end of the extension

Comment: Use `| sponge $inputfile` from the package `moreutils` to use the same file

Answer (score 38):

To do it in place, if your sed supports the -i option, you can do:

```
sed -i '/^string/d' input-file
```

Comment: sed is expecting a file extension for backup when using `-i`, in OS X you must be very pedantic, so explicitly use single quotes: `sed -i '' '/^string/d' input-file`

Comment: In OSX, the default `sed` doesn't even support `-i`!  My personal preference is to never use `-i` and do redirections with the shell instead.

Comment: No `-e` needed?

Comment: It doens't work in ksh? If text has line as 'string-d' then? doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

sed and grep in your answers are missing their friend awk:

```
awk '!/^string/' inputfile > resultfile
```

Comment: I need it to be in the same file

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```
ex -sc g/^string/d -cx file
```

1. `g` select all matching lines
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close